# VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I use FlatList with large number of items. I get following alert from Expo XDE.

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make
>   sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React
>   performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate,
>   etc. {"dt":13861,"prevDt":1498372326027,"contentLength":6624}

I used some optimization approaches to my FlatList for example PureComponent, but I still get this alert. Before I will describe my optimizations, could you tell me if this alert appears always even though FlatList is optimized? Or maybe it indicated actual issues with performance? I ask because performance of my FlatList is good.

Comment: I regularly get this in Dev Mode, I think because of all the other checks that are being done in that case.

Comment: Hi raarts, thanks for comment, actually I get it also when I'm not on Dev mode in Expo.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 105):

I was previously seeing this error. After optimizing my code, I no longer see it. I figured out the problem by adding console.log() statement to the render() function of the Component that creates the FlatList, and the function that renders each item in the List. I noticed that my code was previously re-rendering the entire FlatList and all its items whenever there's a state change to any component on that page (even a component that's not related to the FlatList). I fixed this by converting various components to PureComponents. Here's what my FlatList declaration looks like:

```
<FlatList
    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
    data={allPosts}
    initialNumToRender={7}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
      <Post postJson={item} isGroupAdmin={isGroupAdmin} user={user} />
    }
  />
```

Notice that I'm returning `<Post />` which is a pure component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
class Post extends PureComponent {

  render() { ... }
}
```

This ensures that the FlatList re-renders a  only if the post changes. When I was previously passing a normal function to `renderItem` i.e., a function that does something like this:

```
return (
  <View>
  ...
  </View>
);
```

I noticed that the FlatList was re-rendering all items whenever any item changed. Now, by using a PureComponent, the FlatList only renders the new item added to the list (if the list is already being displayed).

It still takes relative long to render the entire list the first time. However, `initialNumToRender` ensures that the screen is filled up pretty much instantaneously (while the remain items get rendered in the background). And more importantly, after that initial rendering, the FlatList only ever has to render one item at a time (the item that changes).

I found [this post](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#examples) very helpful).

I've just realized this is also explained [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13649)

Comment: Also helpful: http://blog.flaviocaetano.com/post/tips-to-avoid-rerendering-react-native-components/

Comment: I am not sure if my issue is this

Comment: I'm using a PureComponent but it doesn't hide the warning for me, still get " You have a large list
that is slow to update" warning

Comment: is it possible to fixt this in functional component

Comment: in functional component you need to wrap your list item component with React.memo. You also need of courde to make sure only premitive props are being sent to child. If you also send functions/object/arrays etc. them you need to memoize those using useMemo or useCallback.

Answer (score 40):

If you are using a functional component, wrapping the component in `memo` is a good way to prevent unnecessary renders without going through the hassle of converting a functional component to a pure class component. This [post](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-pure-components-functional/) explains it more

follow this example:

In the parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native';
import PostCard from './PostCard';

export const NewsFeeds = props => {
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          initialNumToRender={4}
          refreshing={loading}
          renderItem={_renderitem}
        />
      );
    };

const _renderitem = ({item}) => <PostCard item={item} />;
```

In the child component

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

const PostCard = (props) => {
        return (
            <View>
    
            </View>
        );
    };
    
 export default memo(PostCard);
```

If you are using a class component, make sure your component is a pure component by extending `React. PureComponent` in your class definition

```
class NewsFeeds extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
          data={data}
          initialNumToRender={4}
          refreshing={loading}
          renderItem={_renderitem}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. The memo trick with the functional components worked well for me. I always avoid class components unless a plugin requires it.

Comment: I had no idea there was a functional component memo wrapper, is there any reason to not just always use this? I wrapped all of my app's components in it and performance is vastly improved. Why isn't this the function component default if it performs so much better?

Comment: @AaronWilson because memoizing means keeping the component in memory and may not actually be optimal if the component isn't that expensive to render. If it were the default there would be so much more memory overhead required

Answer (score 24):

I noticed that the answer to this question dosen't proffer solution for those using functional component and hooks. I encountered this problem and i was able to get rid of it by using the hook "useMemo()"

```
<FlatList
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                data={productsState.products}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
                title={item.ProductName}
                subtitle={(item.ProductQuantity) + " " + (item.QuantityType !== 
                null ? item.QuantityType : " ") }
                bottomDivider
                topDivider
                chevron
                checkmark={checkMark}
                onLongPress={() => setCheckMark(!checkMark)}
                rightSubtitle={(item.Currency !== null ? item.Currency: " " ) + 
                " " + (item.productCost !== null ? item.productCost: " " )}
                rightSubtitleStyle={{ marginTop: -20 }}
                badge={{ value: item.sellingPrice, textStyle: { color: 'orange' }, containerStyle: { marginTop: -20 } }}
            />
        )
```

The renderItem function is an expensive computation, because it a long list to render. Instead I memoize it as follows

```
            const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => renderItem, [productsState.product]);

<FlatList
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                data={productsState.products}
                renderItem={memoizedValue}
            />
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <ListItem
            title={item.ProductName}
            subtitle={(item.ProductQuantity) + " " + (item.QuantityType !== 
            null ? item.QuantityType : " ") }
            bottomDivider
            topDivider
            chevron
            checkmark={checkMark}
            onLongPress={() => setCheckMark(!checkMark)}
            rightSubtitle={(item.Currency !== null ? item.Currency: " " ) + 
            " " + (item.productCost !== null ? item.productCost: " " )}
            rightSubtitleStyle={{ marginTop: -20 }}
            badge={{ value: item.sellingPrice, textStyle: { color: 'orange' }, containerStyle: { marginTop: -20 } }}
        />
    )
```

Don't forget to import useMemo from react, inorder to make this work.

Good Luck!

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995990/how-to-use-scrollview-with-nested-flatlist) too, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: i just answered

Comment: All of the memoized items are all dependent on the same piece of state. Wouldn't this make every single item rerender when `productsState.product` changes?

Comment: Yes, it'll only re-render when productsState.product

Comment: still getting same warning

Comment: Yes, I have tried above code. I am using View inside renderItem fn.

Comment: Initially not getting warning but as I scroll the content, warning appears.  code link is given below                
                    
   https://github.com/manawaraquevix/LoginWithOtp/blob/main/useMemo

Answer (score 15):

Adding this prop :

```
initialNumToRender={n}
```

worked for me (`n` being a considerably short amount, for example 5).

Comment: I recommend using this solution before jumping to the other complicated ones in the other answers. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

On top of all the answers given, you can also try setting `removeClippedSubviews` to `true`.

```
<FlatList
  removeClippedSubviews

  // ...other props
/>
```

By enabling `removeClippedSubviews` the memory is freed up when an item disappears from the view.  When you have a long and complex list (i.e. a list of cards) the DOM of each card can get pretty large so it's best to free up the memory when it's not visible.

In addition if you combine with `useCallback()` rather than `useMemo()` you free up a bit more memory when your "data" changes

```
const renderItem = useCallback(originalRenderItem, [data])
```

the `useMemo()` approach will memoize based on the value, but it should really free itself up when the data changes.  By doing `useCallback()` you're getting the benefit of using the "function as a parameter" so you don't need to

```
const renderItem = useCallback(({item, index} 
  => originalRenderItem({item, index}), [data])
```

Thus making it look like a wrapped function without as much reading for the next person.

Doing this two:

- prevents the calling the potentially expensive `render()` function of recently updated components.
- reduces memory used by invisible components
- frees up the memoized data if `data` changes sooner.

Comment: Can You provide some Info about it?

Comment: Let me know if I missed something but adding data to dependencies of the `renderItem` doesn't make much sense and causes harm. Only time you would want to mutate `renderItem` is when you want to use multiple variations of render function for the same list.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, why this bug is happened. The main problem is, when your onEndReached event is happened, im sure you are loading something from server, which means, you need to wait until your loading is finished from server, so after that you can call onEndReached event.

But in your case there is multilple calling of onEndReached event. So when it happens, your application was trying to load datas from server again and again.

Ok, how to solve this problem: you need to create new state, for example
this is realization of infinite scrolling by pagination.

```
const [loader, setLoader] = useState<boolean>(false);

const onEndReached = (page) => {
  if (next && !loader) {
    setPage(page + 1)
  }
}

const loadData = async () => {
  setLoader(true);
  const resp = await getData();
  setLoader(false);
}

<FlatList ...someprops onEndReached={onEndReached} />
```

Answer (score 3):

Also **make sure**, you **don't encapsulate FlatList with ScrollList**.
For me it accidentally appears, because I used native-base, and didn't noticed, that their Component `<Content>` replace ScrollList.

For more Information see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54512633/1256697

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug on Android for `<FlatList />` when `inverted` is `true` which destroys performance, particularly on more recent Android versions: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30034.

The ugly workaround (see the thread) involves patching React Native, using `scaleY: -1`, and inability to use RefreshControl, but there's unfortunately no real alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using functional components you can easily solve it using React.memo

```
import React from "react"
const Component= React.memo((props) => {
  // ... Existing component code ...
})

export default Component
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you still have the error after wrapping list item component with `React.memo()`, probably you are passing an object (or other non-primitive type) as prop. In my case (also using `onEndReached` prop on `FlatList` component to implement infinite scrolling) the warning went away by passing the `JSON.stringify`'ed version of the object prop.

You can test the rerenders by logging inside the list item component.

EDIT: alternatively you can compare previous and next props on a rerender (`shouldComponentUpdate`) by using `React.memo()` as described in this SOF accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62218421/7882342

Answer (score -1):

here is the best answer for you and for performance...

```
import {FlashList} from "@shopify/flash-list";


 <View

    style={{
        width: WIDTH - 40,
        height:HEIGHT,
        marginTop: 16,
        // borderWidth: 1,
        // borderColor: 'red'
    }}>
    <FlashList
        viewabilityConfig={{
            waitForInteraction: true,
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
            minimumViewTime: 1000,
        }}
        estimatedItemSize={200}
        contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingBottom: 150,
            //   transform: [{scaleX: -1}],
        }}
        data={allComments}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            return index;
        }}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            return (
                <AllComentsComponent
                    backgroundColor={item?.status === "publish" ? Colors.dark_green : Colors.redDark}
                    color={item?.status === "publish" ? Colors.green_darker : Colors.DustRed}
                    borderColor={item?.status === "publish" ? Colors.dark_green : Colors.arghavani}
                    title={item?.ContentInfo?.title}
                    status={item.statusFa}
                    id={index}
                    date={item?.createdAt}
                    description={item?.description}
                    onPress={() => {
                    }}
                    // uri={{
                    //     uri: item?.ContentInfo?.contentPoster
                    //         ? item?.ContentInfo?.contentPoster
                    //         : `https://reactnative-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cosmos.jpg`,
                    // }}
                />
            )
        }}
        onEndReached={loadMoreData}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score -3):

add memo to your renderItem component when export it

import React,{memo} from "react";
.
.
.
your code
.
.
.
export default memo(your component name);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).