# Try to use React.memo() api to get rid of warning of too large list, but not sure whether I am doing right

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using `FlatList`. I have a function to render item:

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        ...
      />
    );
  };
```

My `FlatList` uses above `renderItem` function to render item, it is like:

```
   const MyScreen = () => {
    // here is the above renderItem function
    const renderItem = ({item}) => {...}
    ...
    return (
       <View>
         <FlatList
           ...
           renderItem={renderItem}
         />
       </View>)
    }
```

When I run the app, it works, but when I load more items from backend for the list, I get warning:

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices
```

I want to solve this warning, I tried using `React.memo()` api, by wrapping the `renderItem` function like this:

```
   const MyScreen = () => {
    // here is the above renderItem function
    const renderItem = ({item}) => {...}
    ...
    return (
       <View>
         <FlatList
           ...
           renderItem={React.memo(renderItem)}
         />
       </View>)
    }
```

When I run the app again, it crashes with error:

```
TypeError: renderItem is not a function. (In 'renderItem(props)', 'renderItem' is an instance of Object)
```

So, my questions are:

1. Am I in the right direction to solve that warning?
2. How to get rid of that `TypeError: renderItem is not a function ...` error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743904/virtualizedlist-you-have-a-large-list-that-is-slow-to-update
maybe this helps?

Comment: Can you post a answer, how you resolved it.