# React Native no luck with fixing my FlatList - VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update

Tags: memory-leaks, react-native-flatlist, react-virtualized

I have been trying to fix my virtualize list issue du to too many rendering apparently...
this is happening when I go back and forth, from one item here: restaurant (restaurant screen)  to the flatList with the tab bar, I have also been trying to render less items, but even when the limit is down it doesn't seems to work...

****What I use****

I'm using a [animated bottom sheet](https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet) that display the flatList on top of the mapView

**what I tried**

I have been looking ,and tried **[that](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#removeclippedsubviews)** out

and also **[that](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#examples)**

and those **[issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743904/virtualizedlist-you-have-a-large-list-that-is-slow-to-update)** too

I have tried to use the Hook useMemo but apparently it does work for complex stuff such as arrays, or I my config of the dependency was wrong:

```js
const renderMemo = useMemo(() => renderItem, []) //what should be in the array? data? !isLoading ? limit ? ( the limit is change when onEndReached)
```

(code below)

I have tried to make a pure component of my list (renderItem)

**ISSUE**

I still get :
*VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
"contentLength": 5148.66650390625,
"dt": 4164,
"prevDt": 2313,
}*
and in this particular set up after not doing anything for a while I got that error:

```
 _Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
at [native code]:null in dispatchAction
at containers/HomeScreen.js:87:16 in fetchData
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue_
```

I haven't tried shouldComponentUpdate as I don't really understand it... I mean I don't know where to locate it...

where should I head now ? memo maybe?

is there a way maybe to get less render from useEffect

**CODE**

[repo native](https://github.com/voyagebagage/oliv-happyCow-native)

HomeScreen:

```
  const renderContent = () =>
    !isLoading ? (
      <View style={styles.firstParentViewRenderContent}>
       ....
          <FlatListContents
            data={data}
            navigation={navigation}
            setLimit={setLimit}
            limit={limit}
            skip={skip}
            setSkip={setSkip}
            handleColors={handleColors}
          />
      </View>
```

flatListContents component:

```
const handleLoadMore = () => {
   console.trace("handleMore");
   // console.log(limit);
   setIsLoadingMore(true);
   // if (limit > 30) setIsLoadingMore(false);
   if (!isLoading) {
     setLimit(limit + 10);
     setIsLoadingMore(false);
   }
 };

 // const renderMemo = useMemo(() => renderItem, []);

 const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
   return (
     <PureCompFlatlist
       item={item}
       handleColors={handleColors}
       navigation={navigation}
     />
   );
 };
 
  return (
    <FlatList
         data={data}
         keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.placeId)}
         renderItem={renderItem}
         removeClippedSubviews={true}
         maxToRenderPerBatch={20}
         initialNumToRender={5}
         windowSize={limit}
         getItemLayout={(data, index) => {
           return {
             length: styles.flatList.height,
             offset: 25 * styles.flatList.height,
             index,
           };
         }}
         onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
         onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
         // ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
       />
```

PureCompFlat:

```
export class PureCompFlatlist extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { item, handleColors, navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.flatList}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate("Restaurant", {
            id: item.placeId,
            name: item.name,
            description: item.description,
            rating: item.rating,
            thumbnail: item.thumbnail,
            color: handleColors(item.type),
          })
        }
      >
        <Image style={styles.flatListPic} source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }} />
        <View style={styles.flatListContent}>
          <View style={styles.flatListNameType}>
            <Text style={styles.flatListText}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.flatListText}>{item.type}</Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.flatListText}>{item.rating}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.flatListText} numberOfLines={2}>
            {item.description}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

thanks in advance