# How to select one item of the array, when the user selects the contact?

Tags: react-native

What im trying to do is to select one or more phone numbers from the user contact list.

```
function ContactList() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState(contacts)
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
        });
        if (data.length > 0) {
          setContacts(data);
          setFilter(data);
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);
  const searchFilter = (text) => {
    if (text) {
      const newData = contacts.filter((item) => {
        const itemData = item.name ? item.name.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });
      setFilter(newData);
      setSearch(text);
    } else {
      setFilter(contacts);
      setSearch(text);
    }
  };


  const onChangeValue = () => {
    setChecked(!checked)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checked &&
      setData((previous) => [...previous, {phone: contacts}])
  }, [checked]

return(
   <View>
      <CheckBox
          style={{ width: 15, height: 15 }}
          right={true}
          checked={checked}
           onPress={onChangeValue}
       />
   </View>
);

export default ContactList;
```

So far, when the user selects one phone number, it will select all phone numbers on his contact list.
I think I should get with the index only one contact from the list but I don't know how to get there.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: Looks like some optimization issue.
refer to this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743904/virtualizedlist-you-have-a-large-list-that-is-slow-to-update

Answer (score 0):

1. You can maintain a Map for checkboxes.

   const [checked, setChecked] = useState(new Map());
2. on change use index to set values in Map.

   const onChangeValue = (index) => {
   checked.set(index, true)
   };
3. in JSX use like this

   <CheckBox
   style={{ width: 15, height: 15 }}
   right={true}
   checked={checked.get(index)}
   onPress={()=>onChangeValue(index)}
   />

Comment: It works, but it shows this error:```VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc.```

Comment: After I click two contacts or more