# Data inside of Flatlist is rendering extremely slowly on emulator

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, expo

I have a FlatList that renders a `<ListItem.Accordion/>` from React Native Elements, using API data. When using the Android Emulator (Pixel 4 API 29) the emulator drastically slows down when the size of the list increases (147 items). It takes up to 5 seconds for the accordion items to open. When I try to open multiple items while it's stil loading, I get this message in the console:

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
  "contentLength": 8109.0908203125,
  "dt": 1362,
  "prevDt": 1440,
}
```

I looked around and found a couple solutions, one of them was adding `memo`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70179485/10517968. On my mobile android device (Galaxy S9) the list renders within 0.5 second and the accordion opens instantaneously.

**Note:** I tried commenting out the API call and creating a dummy data array with a similar amount of data and the same issue occured.

How do I further improve upon the performance of my code? Perhaps it's just an emulator issue but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

List component:

```
export const HistoryList = () => {
  const users = useSelector(getUsersHistory);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData();
  }, [dispatch]);

  const fetchUserData = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get(
      "http://192/*******",
      {
        auth: {
          username: "**********",
          password: "**********",
        },
      }
    );
    dispatch(getUsersHistoryData(data.data));
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <AccordionListItem item={item} />;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {users && (
        <FlatList
          data={users}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          initialNumToRender={5}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

AccordionListItem Component:

```
const AccordionListItem = ({ item }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ListItem.Accordion
      containerStyle={styles.Tabs}
      content={
        <>
          <ListItem.Content>
            <ListItem.Title
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "bold",
              }}
            >
              {item.Name}
            </ListItem.Title>
            <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto" }}>
              {item.Name}
            </ListItem.Subtitle>
          </ListItem.Content>
        </>
      }
      isExpanded={expanded}
      onPress={() => {
        setExpanded(!expanded);
      }}
    >
      <ListItem.Content style={styles.DetailView}>
        <ListItem.Title style={styles.DetailViewLettering}>
          {item.Type}
        </ListItem.Title>
        <ListItem.Title style={styles.DetailViewLettering}>
          {item.Description}
        </ListItem.Title>
        <ListItem.Title style={styles.DetailViewLettering}>
          {item.Details}
        </ListItem.Title>
        <ListItem.Title style={styles.DetailViewLettering}>
          {item.Key}
        </ListItem.Title>
        <ListItem.Title style={styles.DetailViewLettering}>
          {item.Date}
        </ListItem.Title>
      </ListItem.Content>
    </ListItem.Accordion>
  );
};

export default memo(AccordionListItem);
```