# React Native Reanimated Crashes the App When Using Large List of Data

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

i am not new to RN nor RNReanimated, but i'm curious why am i getting crash on devices and want to find a possible solution for it.

I have a large list of data and i render it through `<Flatlist />`. If I am not using the animations in the list's items, everything scrolls smoothly. However, if i start to use animations from `react-native-reanimated`, i get `Virtualised list: too slow to render` warning and, sometimes, an app crash.

The animation in child component includes 4 elements (it is imitation of an accordion). Here is a list of them in order from light to heavy (imo):

1. Rotate the arrow of the button (up and down, depending on current state of the accordion). Simple `transform.rotate` animation.
2. Margin the top of the list's elements, simple `marginTop` animation.
3. Vertical padding of a child's element. If the list is collapsed I do not want a vertical padding on the element. When the button is pressed, i want to 'unwrap' the component and add vertical padding.
4. Height animation. Since we do not know the exact height of an element, i am using `maxHeight` to dynamically animate the height of element.

List's item component:

```
const ANIMATION_DURATION = 500
const MAX_TABLE_HEIGHT = 700
const SPIN_ROTATION = 180

function ListItem({ entry, intent }) {
  const { newColors, spacing } = useAppTheme()

  const isPreview = intent === 'preview'
  const animationConfig = {
    spin: isPreview ? 0 : SPIN_ROTATION,
    heightAnim: isPreview ? 0 : MAX_TABLE_HEIGHT,
    paddingVertical: isPreview ? 0 : spacing.default,
    wrapperMarginTop: isPreview ? 0 : spacing.default,
  }

  const spin = useSharedValue(animationConfig.spin)
  const heightAnim = useSharedValue(animationConfig.heightAnim)
  const paddingVertical = useSharedValue(animationConfig.paddingVertical)
  const wrapperMarginTop = useSharedValue(animationConfig.wrapperMarginTop)

  const spinStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: withTiming(`${spin.value}deg`, {
          duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
          easing: Easing.bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1),
        }),
      },
    ],
  }))

  const heightStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    maxHeight: withTiming(heightAnim.value, {
      duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
      easing: Easing.bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1),
    }),
  }))

  const rowStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    paddingVertical: withTiming(paddingVertical.value, {
      duration: 700,
      easing: Easing.bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1),
    }),
  }))

  const wrapperStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    marginTop: withTiming(wrapperMarginTop.value, {
      duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
      easing: Easing.bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1),
    }),
  }))

  const onPressChevron = () => {
    if (spin.value === 0) {
      spin.value = SPIN_ROTATION
      heightAnim.value = MAX_TABLE_HEIGHT
      paddingVertical.value = spacing.default
      wrapperMarginTop.value = spacing.default
    } else {
      spin.value = 0
      heightAnim.value = 0
      paddingVertical.value = 0
      wrapperMarginTop.value = 0
    }
  }

  const data = [
    {
      label: '1'
      value: 'value: 1',
    },
    ...etc like this for 10 elements
  ]

  return (
    <Animated.View style={wrapperStyle}>
      <Animated.View
        style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.container, heightStyle])}
      >
        {data.map(({ value, label }) =>
          value !== null ? (
            <DataRow
              animatedStyle={rowStyle}
              key={label}
              label={label}
              value={value}
            />
          ) : null
        )}
      </Animated.View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressChevron} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          {spin.value === 0 ? 'show_more' : 'hide_more'}
        </Text>
        <Animated.View style={spinStyle}>
          <Icon
            name="chevron-down"
            size={20}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Animated.View>
  )
}

export default ListItem
```

and here is `<DataRow />`

```
function DataRow({ label, value, animatedStyle }) {
  const { newColors, spacing } = useAppTheme()

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.row, animatedStyle]}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>{label}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.value}>{value}</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  )
}

export default DataRow
```

I understand that height and vertical padding animation are expensive but i don't understand on how to simplify it in terms of performance?

Edit1: wrapping components in `memo` helps but i get glitchy collapsing animation now.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349156/15327033

Comment: @KeshavBiyani i looked at this answer but it didn't help. After using `memo(Component)` the animations got smoother but height animation is still too expensive when i am using `maxHeight`. maybe there is an approach of doing non-layout animation (translate), or calculate exact height and replace the `maxHeight` with it